# Eureka registry issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am running few test with Eureka and seeing the issue though I shut down the micoservices , it still shows services are up and running, ribbon got the server list and call failed with 404. I went through the eureka docs 85% rule, still this one is tricky. If I disabled the self preservation mode it works, but I don't want to do that as per recommendations in prod. so what is the best configuration to not face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration options are very rich both on the client and the server side, but firstly you must bear in mind that default properties' values are supposed to work for Netflix, where are hundreds of microservices. When you have a small infrastructure, then 85% threshold is pretty strict. One way is to decrease it using *eureka.server.renevalPercentThreshold* property. You need to estimate the best value for your needs, depending mainly on the number of instances that register in Eureka.

When you decide to switch self preservation mode off, then you can configure *eureka.server.evictionIntervalTimerInMs* property, so that services will disappear from registry after time period prefered by yourself. Moreover you can configure (per each instance that registers in Eureka) *eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds*, which is a time that Eureka server waits since it received last heartbeat from the service before it evicts it.

The following classes are very well documented, and you can figure out what is configurable and may be useful for you:
*com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClientConfig.java, com.netflix.appinfo.EurekaInstanceConfig.java, com.netflix.eureka.EurekaServerConfig.java*